# On lifts of a trajectory of a quadratic differential

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface of genus $g\ge 2$ and $q$ a holomorphic quadratic differential on $X$. The differential $q$ defines a flat metric with conical singularities on $X$: if $q=f(z)dz^2$ locally then the metric is $|f(z)|dzd\overline{z}$. Let $l$ be a trajectory for $q$ on $X$, i.e. a complete geodesic for the singular metric which does not meet any singular point and so is of constant direction on $X$. It is known (it is proven for example in the book by Strebel) that the image of $l$ is dense in a domain of $X$.

Let $\pi:(\widetilde{X},\widetilde{q})\rightarrow (X,q)$ be a locally diffeomorphic universal cover.

It is my understanding that a lift $\widetilde{l}$ of $l$ is made like in the following picture:

In particular $\widetilde{l}$ is proper ($\widetilde{X}$ is written as $\mathbb{H}^2$).

[image: pic1]

Now let $g:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ be an arc in $X$ such that $l$ intersects $g$ infinitely many times and in particular $l(0)\in g([0,1])$. Now let $l'(t):=l(t+t_0), t_0\neq 0$ (i.e. $l'$ is a reparametrization of $l$) such that $l'(0)\in g([0,1])$.

If I consider $\widetilde{g}$ a lift of $g$ then there are two lifts $\widetilde{l}$ and $\widetilde{l}'$ of $l$ and $l'$ respectively such that $\widetilde{l}(0)\in \widetilde{g}([0,1])$ and $\widetilde{l}'(0)\in \widetilde{g}([0,1])$

My question is: **are the images of $\widetilde{l}$ and $\widetilde{l}'$ disjoint?**

My guess is yes, they are made like in this picture:

[image: pic2]

Am I right?

Comment: There are several mistakes in your question. One is that each trajectory is dense, this is completely false. What is true is that "most trajectories'' are dense. Second, you have to define properly "intersects infinitely many times". Third, with your definition of a lift, you are actually allowing $\tilde l$ and $\tilde l'$ to be the same. You have to be more careful here. The right thing to say is that $\tilde l'$ is obtained from $\tilde l$ by applying a nontrivial covering transformation. You also have to assume that $l$ is not periodic. Then the answer to your question is Yes.